# Is it good to use boost::tuple<bool, T> to indicate if T was found or not?

Tags: c++, boost

Assume we need a function that returns something. But that something can be not found. I see options:

```
1. T find(bool &ok); //return default T value if not found
```

We can make a struct:

```
template <typename T>
class CheckableValue
{
public:
    CheckableValue(),
    _hasValue(false)
    {

    }
    CheckableValue(const T &t):
    _value(t),
    _hasValue(true)
    {

    }

    inline bool hasValue() const {return _hasValue}
    const T &value() const
    {
        assert(hasValue());
        return _value;
    }

private:
    T _value;
    bool _hasValue;
};
```

and make the function:

```
2. CheckableValue<T> find();
```

Or we can use:

```
3.boost::tuple<bool, T> find()
```

What do you think is preferable ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I prefer:

```
4. boost::optional<T> find();
```

The problem with the tuple is that the `T` part is invalid when the `bool` part is false; this behaviour is not enforced by the tuple. Your CheckableValue class is the same remedy as `boost::optional` for the same problem.

Comment: boost optional http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html is really great. I use it in many places that look like the poster's one.

Answer (score 0):

> returns something. But that something can be not found.

Are you actually planning to return a copy, or some kind of reference for the thing? "not found" implies that the function works by "finding" a pre-existing value in a data structure somewhere.

In that case, the simple solution is to return a pointer to the existing value, using NULL for not-found.

Comment: It can not necessary be in some collection. The value can be computed on the go and returned. But if some input was incorrect it may raise a flag, indicating bad input. Returning pointer to the just allocated on the heap object is not convenient i think (you may say that auto_ptr will do the work, but I think boost::optional is much better)